# "Focus on" or "be focused on": what're the nuances?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

After viewing a couple of threads on the Internet, I found that both the legitimacy or the explanation of "focus on" (active voice form) and "be focused on" (passive voice form) seemed controversial. Some said they were the same (e.g. in [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/focus-on-be-focused-on.2920889/) and [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/focus-on-vs-be-focused-on.2625649/) threads); [some](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/focus-on-be-focused-on.2508106/) argued that the active case was preferable; [some](https://www.englishforums.com/English/FocusOnBeFocusedOn/wgkkx/post.htm) tried to explain the subtleties between the two, stating that the intransitive case might "be a little less forceful."

What's more confusing, both cases can appear in the same sentence. As in [Remarks by President Trump in Meeting with Vice Premier Liu He of the People’s Republic of China](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/remarks-president-trump-meeting-vice-premier-liu-peoples-republic-china/?utm_source=link&utm_medium=header):

> Both sides agree this agreement is worth nothing — if we can get an agreement, it’s worth nothing without enforcement.  That’s been your instruction from the beginning.  So **we’re focusing** — we have a lot more issues to cover, but we **focused on** the structural issues — the ones that **you’ve been so focused on** — and we talked about enforcement, enforcement, enforcement.

So, my questions are:

1. What're the nuances between "focus on" and "be focused on"?
2. For some tricky sentence like "You've been so focused on the stage", should I interpret it as "You focus on the stage very much" or "People focus on you on the stage very much"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a reason that these active-voice and passive-voice constructions carry very similar meanings.   The verb *to focus* is ergative.

> The lens focuses rays of light.
>   Nothing else focuses the mind like a deadline.

Sentences like these use an ordinary transitive active-voice construction.   The subject represents a semantic *actor* or *agent*.   The direct object represents a semantic *patient*.

These semantic roles still exist in passive-voice constructions of this verb.   In the passive voice, the subject represents the patient.   The actor or agent, if represented at all, is represented by an adjunct:

> Our attention is focused on this problem.
>   This light is focused by a series of lenses and mirrors.

These semantic roles do not exists in an ergative clause.   In this case, the subject represents something that isn't quite an agent and isn't quite a patient, but shares some similarities with both of those roles.   We can see these similarities when we compare an ergative clause to ordinary transitive clauses:

> We focused on the structural issues.
>   We focused ourselves on the structural issues.
>   We focused our attention on the structural issues.
>   We were focused on the structural issues.

The passive-voice construction allows something that the ergative construction doesn't.   The passive voice employs a participle, and these participles often accept modifiers like "very" and "so":

> * We very focused on the structural issues.
>      We were very focused on the structural issues.

> the [issues] that you've been so focused on
>   You've been so focused on the stage.

Here, the phrase "so focused" works.

That last example sentence might mean several things.   It's impossible to tell from the grammar alone whether "on the stage" represents the target of focusing or the location of being.   Whatever the sentence is intended to mean, it does not mean that people focus on you.

Comment: So the short answer is all forms ("A meeting/person focuses/is focused on something") are correct?